# Jersey response body empty in client

Tags: java, service, jersey

I had a server and I add  a service with the same logical as the existing ones. So I have this code:

```
    @RolesAllowed({"authenticated", "administrator"})
    @Path("notifications/{uuid}")
    @Produces("application/json")
@GET
public Response getNotifications(@Context SecurityContext sc, @PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
    UserPrincipal requestingUser = (UserPrincipal) sc.getUserPrincipal();
    CountNotiListItem notifications = customerService.getNotifications(requestingUser, uuid);
    return Response.ok().entity(notifications).build();
}
```

The notifications object is not null. The response is created and has the same format as in the other services, but on client side I have 200 OK response with empty "_body" [_body: {}] Why it is null? Should I modify something more in order to have _body filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got a test case where you try to serialize and de-serialize `CountNotiListItem`  to/from JSON? if `notifications` is actually non-empty, does it show up in that test? That would be my start to debugging this.

Comment: Actually I don't know if I had to add some code to serialize and de-serialize. I suposed I had to add it but as the project is already made (for an old worked) and I have just to add this service. I don't know how it works (I never worked with spring/jersey services). If this is the task please help me where to include it. I show you what is inside each object.

notifications=> Object with 4 properties.
Response.ok().entity(notifications).build() => { entity = CountNotiListItem notifications object, entityType = me.tomsen.restapi.eib.api.CountNotiListItem, Headers= {}, statustype= OK }

Comment: Should I add serialization and deserialization code in "me.tomsen.restapi.eib.api.CountNotiListItem"?

Comment: That depends. As other calls are working, I'm assuming that there is a JSON provider registered with Jersey. It will most likely be a matter of including the proper annotations. Look at the classes that are getting returned. Most likely @XmlRootElement

Comment: Thank you! you solve my problem! I needed getters and setters in my me.tomsen.restapi.eib.api.CountNotiListItem class XD I'm so dumb sometimes :P

Comment: Glad to help, nice that you learned something (and not knowing all doens't make one dumb).